# How to fix incorrect XML tags in a Berkeley DB file

Tags: python, berkeley-db

I have a Berkeley DB file which has some data in a record which is corrupt.

The record contains xml and the xml tag is not correct.

In one of the records contains:

```
"<modifications></modificatio"
```

How can i edit this record to fix this in

```
"<modifications></modifications>"
```

Comment: Your berkely db file isn't corrupt (which is what your title suggests). Please edit the question with more details about what's wrong *specifically* with this xml record.

Comment: Thks hope this is more specific.

Comment: how big is the file? If you simply are missing three characters, you could use your editor's find-and-replace command interactively to fix your file.

Comment: I fix it with a texteditor but then you get the following error: "bsddb.db.DBInvalidArgError in /usr/lib/python2.4/bsddb/__init__.py:298 in hashopen: (22, 'Invalid argument -- /price_arrivaldate.db: file size not a multiple of the pagesize')"

Comment: No, you can't add characters to a binary database file using your text editor.  I hope you kept a backup.

Comment: Yes i have, do you know how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Berkeley database file is a binary file containing database records that have been placed there by an application.

You would typically "edit" the file using whatever tool you used to generate it in the first place.  If that's not available to you, the easiest solution is probably to use the `db_dump` and `db_load` commands.

The `db_dump` command transforms a database into a text format, like this:

```
$ db_dump my_broken_database
format=print
type=hash
h_nelem=77
db_pagesize=4096
HEADER=END
 key1\00
 this is a value\00
 key2\00
 this is another value\00
DATA=END
```

You can dump this to a file...

```
$ db_dump my_broken_database > data.txt
```

... and edit this with your favorite text editor.  Once you've made your edits, you feed it to `db_load` to regenerate the database:

```
$ db_load my_fixed_database < data.txt
```